# Saving a file with a Cyrillic name

Tags: ruby, file, character-encoding, filenames

How to correctly save a file with a Cyrillic name?

Now the file name looks like this: "РњР°РєСЃРёРј Р—РёРЅСЏРєРѕРІ feat. Indigo - You And Me Only". The correct name is "Максим Зиняков feat. Indigo - You And Me Only".

I get the file from HTTP URL:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get(url).save_as("#{mp3_dir}/#{title}.mp3")
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: If you are dealing with unicode, I strongly suggest 1.9.2 as it is a lot nicer.

Comment: Be sure to match the encoding of the site you are scraping with the one used by your filesystem.

Comment: If encoding is different? Site has windows-1251.

Comment: You probably have to convert it to UTF-8 somehow then. Try using `iconv` library (or move to 1.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As somebody mentioned, you probably need to convert the `title` string to utf-8 using `iconv`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'iconv'

agent = Mechanize.new
# If source encoding is indeed windows-1251, 'from' is CP1251
title = Iconv.conv('UTF8', 'CP1251', title)
agent.get(url).save_as("#{mp3_dir}/#{title}.mp3")
```